# Wicket - How to call another page using a ListView items

Tags: java, html, wicket

When a user clicks on an item of my ListView, I would like it to load another page with the informations of the clicked row. I have tried adding an onClick event to the items, like this:

```
item.add(new AjaxFormValidatingBehavior(ClientSearchForm.this, "onclick") {

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        ClientPage.this.setResponsePage(new EditClientPage());
    }
});
```

But I'm not sure how I can load my other page. Should I need to just instantiate it?

EDIT: Using the above code worked, but it only loads when the first item is clicked.

HTML as requested.

```
<table border="1" wicket:id="clientTable" id="client-table">
                    <tr wicket:id="clientRow" id="client-row">
                        <td>
                            <span wicket:id="row1"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <span wicket:id="row2"></span>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: What's the part that you're having trouble with? Setting different pages for different items?

Comment: @biziclop I actually want all the items to load the same page (EditClientPage will receive a variable at the constructor). The problem is that using this method only the first item loads the page.

Comment: I see. How about adding a `Link` to the item, and everything that you currently add to the item, you add under the link instead? The markup for the link should be a `<div>` to keep it simple.

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Do you get any JavaScript error when you click on the items different from the first?

Comment: @AndreaDelBene No erros. I actually managed to get it working using AjaxEventBehavior. But I'm still bugged as to why this isn't working with AjaxFormValidatingBehavior.

Comment: @biziclop No success with links =/

Comment: First of all, check my answer :) Secondly, could you post the relevant html bit too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a few tests and your solution worked fine for me.

So I suspect the problem is in your markup, which may not support the onclick event.

Here's my working sample:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {

        add( new Label( "label", parameters.getString( "param")));

        add( new ListView( "list", Arrays.asList( "foo", "bar") ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
                item.add( new Label( "label", "item model is "+item.getModelObject() ) );
                item.add( new AjaxEventBehavior( "onclick") {

                    @Override
                    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        PageParameters pp = new PageParameters( "param="+item.getModelObject() );
                        setResponsePage( new HomePage( pp ) );
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wicket Quickstart Archetype Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span wicket:id="label">message will be here</span>
        <div wicket:id="list">Static stuff and <span wicket:id="label">dynamic stuff</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that was the difference that mattered. Good to know.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot. But why with the other event only the first row was working with the onclick is still a mistery to me.